# NoReverseMatch at / in pyCharm using Django

Tags: python, django, windows, pycharm, django-urls

On running my project with PyCharm as a django project on Windows, I am getting the above error. However, when I run this on my CentOS machine, all my pages are rendered fine. So, I was wondering if there is some change I need to make in order to make it compatible on Windows? Have you faced this issue before?

My code:

HTML file in templates:

```
<a href={% url "my_view" variable1 variable2 %}><b> View Display </b></a>
```

app_name1/views.py

```
def my_view(request, variable1, variable2):
    #view function
```

app_name1/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from app_name1 import views

urlpatterns = patterns('app_name1.views',
url(r'^my_view/(?P<variable1>\d+)/(?P<variable2>\w+)/$', 'my_view', name='myview'),
)
```

Comment: Please provide more detailed information about your urls and where you use a reverse url lookup.

Comment: Nope. paste traceback here ?

Comment: I have added a code snippet to elaborate the problem

Answer (score 0):

You named your url `myview` (`name='myview'`) but in your template you are requesting for `my_view` (`{% url "my_view" variable1 variable2 %}`).

Use `{% url "myview" variable1 variable2 %}` instead or change your url name to `my_view`.